# How can I sum up values from a json string?

Tags: php, json

I get the following json data from a database:

```
[{"type":"Sig","value":"0.0"},{"type":"SH","value":"9.95"},{"type":"COD","value":"6.95"}][{"type":"Sig","value":"0.0"},{"type":"SH","value":"9.95"},{"type":"COD","value":"6.95"}][{"type":"Sig","value":"0.0"},{"type":"SH","value":"9.95"},{"type":"COD","value":"6.95"}][{"type":"Sig","value":"0.0"},{"type":"SH","value":"9.95"},{"type":"COD","value":"6.95"}]
```

I'm trying to add all `value` values together, so: 9.95 + 6.95 ... so that I get 67.6 as result.

I tried the below code, but I am getting 16.9 as repeated values.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count - 1 ; $i++) {

    $charge = $service[$i]['charge']; 
    $serviceValue = json_decode($charge, true); 
    $totalservice = 0;

    foreach ($serviceValue as $key => $value)      {              
        $totalservice += $value['service_value'];
    }
    echo $totalservice;                
}
```

Comment: Set `$totalservice = 0;` outside `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder now it works fine. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($json); // Decode the JSON to OBJ

// Now loop and find the SUM
$total = 0;
foreach ($jsonObj as $item){
    $total =+ $item->value;
}

// Print the SUM
echo "Sum : $total";
```

**Note:- In your code  `$totalservice` beome `0` every time when loop goes to next  iteration and that's why you are getting same value repeated time. So do like (what @u_mulder said) :-**

```
$totalservice = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count-1 ; $i++) {
.....//rest code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @anant . Got the solution by keeping $totalservice=0 outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I have made the below changes. It works fine.

```
$totalservice = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count-1 ; $i++) {
    $charge = $service[$i]['charge']; 
    $serviceValue = json_decode($charge, true); 

    foreach ($serviceValue as $key => $value)      {              
        $totalservice+= $value['service_value'];
    }
    echo $totalservice;                
    }
```

Thanks for the help